# Scala: Not a legal formal parameter when trying to call a function who has a predicate as one of its argument

Tags: scala

Here is the code that I'm trying to execute,

`type Set = scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]`

defined type alias Set

`def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = Set(1,2,3)`

filter: (s: Set, p: Int => Boolean)Set

`filter(Set(1,2,3), (4 => 2 < 3))`

**error:** not a legal formal parameter
       filter(Set(3,4), (4 => 2<3))

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Should there not be a parameter name like the `x` in `filter(Set(1,2,3), (x => x < 3))`?

Comment: Tip: `filter(Set(1,2,3), the4 => (2 < 2))`

Comment: It worked FrankPI.. Ahh got it. Its like f(x) = x < 3. Right? Thanks. Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is neither predicate, nor value, you can't name lambda parameter as just '4', you can't pass 4 into boolean. Correct syntax could be:

```
filter(Set(1,2,3), the4 => (2 < 2))
```

Or perhaps:

```
filter(Set(1,2,3), x => (x < 2))
```

as [@FrankPI said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340085/scala-not-a-legal-formal-parameter-when-trying-to-call-a-function-who-has-a-pre/18340196#comment26920688_18340085)

Comment: @pedrofurla did you meant `filter(Set(1,2,3), \`4\` => (2 < 2))`?